# How to split table column if row reach the maximum height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a data that loop from database to table. But I only need 1 column except if the row exceed the limit of my height it should be dynamically create another column or transfer the data to the other column and split my datas to that new column, is that possible?

```
echo'<table>';
for($res->result() as $rows){
    echo'<tr>';
        echo'<td>'.$rows-Name.'</td>';
    echo'</tr>';
}
echo'</table>';
```

The output is this

```
Cynthia Abanes 
Melde Feliciano 
Chelsea MacKinnon 
Christine Kostiuk 
Erick 
Vicky Maglinao 
Norman Murehwa 
Ronda 
Elvira Rivera 
Hiyasmin Gajudo 
Mary Jane Reyes 
Ronnie De Guzman 
Annaliza Camino 
Edwin Marino
Lucelle Caseres 
Gayly Reniedo
Joseph Javier 
Herminigildo Urbano 
Herminigildo UrbanO
```

It should be like this

```
Cynthia Abanes       Ronda             Gayly Reniedo
Melde Feliciano      Hiyasmin Gajudo   Joseph Javier 
Chelsea MacKinnon    Mary Jane Reyes   Herminigildo Urbano 
Christine Kostiuk    Ronnie De Guzman  Herminigildo UrbanO
Erick                Annaliza Camino 
Vicky Maglinao       Edwin Marino
Norman Murehwa       Lucelle Caseres
```

Comment: @caramba I mean its the div height

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution using [`flexbox`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). Instead of printing your data into a table(`table`) use a list (`ul`).

**Note:** Adjusting the height will automatically move the data to next column.

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 130px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Cynthia Abanes</li>
  <li>Melde Feliciano</li>
  <li>Chelsea MacKinnon</li>
  <li>Christine Kostiuk</li>
  <li>Erick</li>
  <li>Vicky Maglinao</li>
  <li>Norman Murehwa</li>
  <li>Ronda</li>
  <li>Elvira Rivera</li>
  <li>Hiyasmin Gajudo</li>
  <li>Mary Jane Reyes</li>
  <li>Ronnie De Guzman</li>
  <li>Annaliza Camino</li>
  <li>Edwin Marino</li>
  <li>Lucelle Caseres</li>
  <li>Gayly Reniedo</li>
  <li>Joseph Javier</li>
  <li>Herminigildo Urbano</li>
  <li>Herminigildo UrbanO</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice solution with no plugin. I am tempted to erase my answer as it has a dependency on a plugin and a css-only solution is better for many reasons. Good work.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jquery plugin solution [Columnizer](http://welcome.totheinter.net/columnizer-jquery-plugin.). Also take a look at [this worked example.](http://webweaversworld.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/cssjquery-solution-for-creating-multi.html)

You may need to alter your output from table to divs or unordered-list.

Looks quite straightforward.

Have not copied any code here because the plugin is well documented with many examples and the blog entry is also clearly written.

Comment: You missed to add the link!

Answer (score 0):

The "normal" way is to check for the `width` and not for the height. For different reasons one of them is that you are limited of the width especially with mobile devices and that's why someone invetend [CSS MedaQueries](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)

With Media Queries you could make a simple solution like so:

```css
table td {
  background-color: orange;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
  table td {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 0 2px 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cynthia Abanes</td>
        <td>Melde Feliciano</td>
        <td>Chelsea MacKinnon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Christine Kostiuk</td>
        <td>Erick</td>
        <td>Vicky Maglinao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Norman Murehwa</td>
        <td>Ronda</td>
        <td>Elvira Rivera</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hiyasmin Gajudo</td>
        <td>Mary Jane Reyes</td>
        <td>Ronnie De Guzman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Annaliza Camino</td>
        <td>Edwin Marin</td>
        <td>Lucelle Caseres</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gayly Renied</td>
        <td>Joseph Javier</td>
        <td>Herminigildo Urbano</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herminigildo Urban</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here is a jsFiddle so you can resize your screen and see how it works](https://jsfiddle.net/7fa9s7p9/)

But now you sayd you want to check for the height. So you will not be able to know the height on the server so you need to check/change it with javascript. Something like so this could be a solution:

```js
if($('table').height() > $(window).height()) {
 $('table').addClass('table-is-to-big')
} else {
 $('table').removeClass('table-is-to-big')
}
```

```css
table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

table td {
  background-color: orange;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 2px 0;
}

table.table-is-to-big {
  border:solid 5px red;
}

table.table-is-to-big td {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Cynthia Abanes</td>
        <td>Melde Feliciano</td>
        <td>Chelsea MacKinnon</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Christine Kostiuk</td>
        <td>Erick</td>
        <td>Vicky Maglinao</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Norman Murehwa</td>
        <td>Ronda</td>
        <td>Elvira Rivera</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Hiyasmin Gajudo</td>
        <td>Mary Jane Reyes</td>
        <td>Ronnie De Guzman</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Annaliza Camino</td>
        <td>Edwin Marin</td>
        <td>Lucelle Caseres</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Gayly Renied</td>
        <td>Joseph Javier</td>
        <td>Herminigildo Urbano</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Herminigildo Urban</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here is fiddle, if height is big enough is one big column else like table](https://jsfiddle.net/7fa9s7p9/1/)